# Measure std::system's real execution time in C++

Tags: c++, performance, time, stl

Is it possible to measure `std::system(...)`'s execution time ?

Or maybe the function returns immediately and it's not possible, and in this case is there any other way to measure the execution of a forked program ?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `system` is about executing a command. Assume it is linux since you used 'fork'. `system("time " YOUR_COMMAND)` is enough, although the time consumption is printed out to the terminal.

Comment: If you want to measure the `system` call time like other subroutines, you can turn to `rdtsc`/`gettimeofday`/...(`time` in time.h is not recommended since it can only return current second, and is not useful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you are looking at a system that is neither POSIX with a sh-like shell nor Windows, `std::system` is synchronous and returns the result of the command. You can use the standard [high resolution timer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) to measure wall time:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto before = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::system("sleep 3");
    auto after = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(
        after - before);

    std::cout << "It took " << duration.count() << " microseconds\n";
}
```

If you're rather interested in the amount of CPU time that the process used, I don't think that C++ has a standard and cross-platform way of offering that to you.

Comment: Thanks for answering. My problem was in fact that `std::system` was executing too quickly. So, now I can measure exactly how quickly :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this code (for Linux & POSIX),

```
 #include<time.h>
 #include<sys/types.h>
 #include<sys/wait.h>
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 struct tms st_time;
 struct tms ed_time;
 int main()
 {
   times(&st_time);
   std::system("your call");
   times(&ed_time);
   std::cout<<"Total child process time ="
            <<((ed_time.tms_cutime - st_time.tms_cutime)
                +(ed_time.tms_cstime - st_time.tms_cstime))/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
 }
```

Comment: Won't work. On POSIX systems `clock()` -see [clock(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/clock.3.html)...- gives an approximation of the current process CPU time (excluding child processes). Windows is known to be defective because its `clock` gives -incorrectly- a crude approximation of real elapsed time

Comment: system() is blocking, it waits until it returns, then the status is examined if it returned normally, only then is the time calculated, can you tell me whats wrong? @BasileStarynkevitch

Comment: `clock` measures the processor time of the current process (excluding child processes)

Comment: I understand that but system() is BLOCKING, which means parent is suspended until system returns, thats why clock() is called to get the time difference between the previous call.

Comment: Indeed, but while the parent process is blocked, its processor time don't change (till some `waitpid` or `wait` succeeds). Try your program (on Linux) with a CPU time consuming command such as e.g. `/usr/games/primes 1 1000000000 > /tmp/primeslist`

Comment: Yes, you are right! i have edited my code to implement another logic @BasileStarynkevitch. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: BTW, the new variant also measures the (tiny amount of) time spent in `/bin/sh`

Answer (score 1):

It is implementation specific (since, AFAIU, the C++ standard does not tell much about the command processor used by `std::system`; that command processor might not even run any external processes).

But let's focus **on Linux** (or at least on other POSIX like systems). Then, you could use the lower level system calls [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [wait4(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait4.2.html) and use the `struct rusage` (see [getrusage(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html) for details) filled by that successful `wait4` call, notably to get the CPU time.  If you want just the elapsed *real* time, use [`<chrono>` C++ facilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) (or lower-level [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7$.html) things such as [clock_gettime(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_getttime.2.html)...)

Notice that the [clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/clock) standard C function gives information about *processor time* (in the *current* [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))) so won't measure what a forked child process (by `std::system`) would consume.